# VBA default response to a comaddin

Tags: vba, excel, comaddin

My excel contains a comaddin that is implemented by the company I work for, in which when the user saves a file it brings up a dialogue box in which they have to specify the type of document it is (e.g. public, confidential etc...). As I am unable to disable this (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367531/disable-but-not-disconnect-excel-com-addin-with-vba) my alternative thought was whether there was a way to implement a default response to this within the vba (e.g. always select public when this dialogue box appears). Does anyone know whether this is viable and if so how I would go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if the addin is setting a .CustomDocumentProperty?  If so, setting it before saving may stop the addin dialogue from firing.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm a bit of a newbie to developing/VBA, are you able to prove any further details on this (i.e. how would I check/change this)? Thanks.

Comment: Are you operating within a SharePoint environment?

Comment: The document itself has not been uploaded to any sharepoint if that's what you mean...

Comment: So you get the message when you try to upload it to SharePoint?

Comment: The user gets the dialogue box when trying to save to any location irrespective of where it's being saved.